# GRUB ignores my cryptdevice parameter in /etc/default/grub

Tags: arch-linux, grub, luks, initramfs, crypttab

I want to create setup with a encrypted root filesystem on my Arch Linux installation, so when I successfully mounted my /boot and /boot/efi partitions, I'm contuning with grub installation with `grub`, `efibootmgr` and `os-prober` packages.

Then I'm making these changes on my /etc/default/grub file for both `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` lines:

```
"net.ifnames=0 cryptdevice=UUID=<UUID of the encrypted **partition**>:cr_root root=/dev/mapper/cr_root"
```

But however, when I run `grub-install` then `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`, I cannot see `cryptdevice` parameter I specified in my `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file. Instead of that, I'm seeing `root=<UUID of the encrypted **filesystem** inside the LUKS container>`. So therefore, when I reboot to that system, bootloader can successfully load the kernel, but kernel cannot see the actual root filesystem because it's looking for the device with UUID of encrypted **filesystem inside the LUKS container**, not the **partition**. Thus, it's says that `waiting for the device /dev/disk/by-uuid/uuid-of-the-encrypted-filesystem` when attempting to boot the system, but cannot continue to the boot and neither asks for the decryption password.

I've also tried adding root filesystem's entry to `/etc/crypttab` then re-running `mkinitcpio`, and also regenerating my `grub.cfg`, nothing worked.

Comment: Did you check `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` right after `grub-mkconfig` or did you really just check the content of the boot entry when you got to the grub menu? Also, did you run `grub-mkconfig` inside the chroot of your new installation?

Comment: @TomYan I checked my `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` both right after `grub-mkconfig` and entry variables in the boot menu's editing section, and yes, I ran `grub-mkconfig` inside the chroot (using `arch-chroot`).

Comment: No idea then. Just in case, also make sure you edited the `/etc/default/grub` of the new installation (e.g. check inside chroot).

Comment: Do you have the luks container properly defined at /etc/crypttab? Also, your description was not entirely clear to me, I infer that the boot partition with the kernel is not encrypted, right?